# how to set multiple strings from array next to each other

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a overview of products which I want to place next to each other in a table like this  : "product1, $1,35;product2, $1,50;product3, $5,50"

But now when I print them they get like this on my screen:

[image]

here is a `var_dump` of my json decoded array:

```
array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(1) ["product_name"]=> string(12) "Broodje Kaas" ["product_quantity"]=> int(1) ["product_price"]=> int(205) } array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(2) ["product_name"]=> string(11) "Broodje ham" ["product_quantity"]=> int(3) ["product_price"]=> int(107) } array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(1) ["product_name"]=> string(10) "Broodje ei" ["product_quanity"]=> int(1) ["product_price"]=> int(205) } array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(2) ["product_name"]=> string(11) "Broodje kip" ["product_quanity"]=> int(3) ["product_price"]=> int(107) } array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(1) ["product_name"]=> string(12) "Broodje Kaas" ["product_quanity"]=> int(1) ["product_price"]=> int(205) } array(4) { ["product_id"]=> int(2) ["product_name"]=> string(11) "Broodje ham" ["product_quanity"]=> int(3) ["product_price"]=> int(107) }
```

and a `var_dump` of my $productids:

```
array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quantity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quantity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 2,50 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:08:43 [order_state] => 1 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje ei","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje kip","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 3,00 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:04:38 [order_state] => 0 [order_is_paid] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 5,60 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 14:40:51 [order_state] => 2 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quantity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quantity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 2,50 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:08:43 [order_state] => 1 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje ei","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje kip","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 3,00 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:04:38 [order_state] => 0 [order_is_paid] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 5,60 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 14:40:51 [order_state] => 2 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quantity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quantity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 2,50 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:08:43 [order_state] => 1 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje ei","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje kip","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 3,00 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 18:04:38 [order_state] => 0 [order_is_paid] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [order_items] => [{"product_id":1,"product_name":"Broodje Kaas","product_quanity":1,"product_price":205},{"product_id":2,"product_name":"Broodje ham","product_quanity":3,"product_price":107}] [order_price] => 5,60 [order_date] => 2017-10-12 14:40:51 [order_state] => 2 [order_is_paid] => 1 ) )
```

and here is my code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<?php $output = "<tr><th># </th><th>Producten </th><th>Prijs </th></tr>";?>
<tbody>
<tr>
```

Uw bestelde producten

```
<?php foreach ($productsids as $value) {

    $output .= "<tr>";
    $orderitems = json_decode($value['order_items'], true);
    $output .= "<td>" .$value['id']. "</td>";

    foreach ($orderitems as $item) {
        var_dump($item);

        $output .= "<td>" .$item['product_name']. "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" .$item['product_price']. "</td>";

        //$output .= "<td>" .$item['product_quantity']. "</td>";

    }
    $output .= "</tr>";

}
echo $output;
?>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you print $productsids print_r($productsids ) ?

Comment: @RavinderReddy this will appear : https://gyazo.com/74dcf79df527d5730f43df55be2bf99b

Comment: Image wont work. paste the code.

Comment: @RavinderReddy uhh like this ? :

Comment: Too many characters, I am going to paste It in the question

Comment: Yes, please update the BODY of the question when asked for details like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting one product per row, you need to handle tr inside the foreach of sub products, and span them with that first cell with the row number in it.

Something like this:

```
foreach ($productsids as $value) {
    $orderitems = json_decode($value['order_items'], true);
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= '<td rowspan="'. count($orderitems) .'">' . $value['id'] . "</td>";
    foreach ($orderitems as $r => $item) {
        if ($r!=0) { $output .= "</tr><tr>"; }
        $output .= "<td>" . $item['product_name'] . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $item['product_price'] . "</td>";
    }
    $output .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You may still need to add some checks and balances. For example, handle what happens if the order has no products (a rowspan=0 is messy in html).